# How to display file upload error message on ajax error?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I'd like to display file upload error on an ajax alert error message.

This is my ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        url         : url,
        type        : 'POST',
        cache       : false,
        contentType : false,
        processData : false,
        data        : all_data,
        dataType    : 'JSON',
        success     : function(data)
        {
            if (data.result != 0) {
                toastr.options = {
                    closeButton : false,
                    progressBar : false,
                    showMethod  : 'slideDown',
                    timeOut     : 3000
                };

                toastr.success('UPLOAD SUCCESS', 'Attention...');

                if(activeid != 0){
                    if($("#tl_responder").val() != "" && $("#tl_dept").val() != "" && $("#tl_jawab").val() != ""){
                        toastr.success('MAIL IS SENT', 'ATTENTION...');
                    }
                }

            } else { window.location.href = "<?php print base_url(); ?>complaint/detail?id=" + data.result + "#reloadafteradd"; }

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown, data)
        {
            toastr.options = {
                closeButton : false,
                progressBar : false,
                showMethod  : 'slideDown',
                timeOut     : 3000
            };
            toastr.error(errorThrown, 'Error...'); //THIS IS THE AJAX ERROR ALERT
           if(!errorThrown){ toastr.error(data.upl_error, 'Error...'); }//This is not working

        }
    });
```

The AJAX error alert only shows alert when AJAX is not working. I'd like to display the file upload error here.

This is my controller that handle file upload when not uploading:

```
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('file')){

        $response_array = array ('upl_error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        echo json_encode($response_array);
        //return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send a flag to specify if file uploaded successfully or not to do this send a success flag  from your php code like this:

**PHP CODE**

```
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('file')){
    // file not  uploaded
    $response_array = array ('success'=0,'upl_error' =>   $this->upload->display_errors('', ''));
    echo json_encode($response_array);

}
else
{
  // file uploaded
   echo json_encode(array("success"=>1));
}
```

And then in your ajax success callback function you need to check that success flag like this

**jQuery CODE**

```
 $.ajax({
        url         : url,
        type        : 'POST',
        cache       : false,
        contentType : false,
        processData : false,
        data        : all_data,
        dataType    : 'JSON',
        success     : function(data)
        {
           // if file upload success
            if (data.success == 1) {

               alert("File uploaed success");

            } 
            // file not uploaded
            else { 
                alert(data.upl_error);
            }

        }
});
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Umm.. in my AJAX success, there's an alert of successfully inserting the data. If the file is not uploaded, the data is not inserted but the ajax is working. How do I sent the `echo $this->upload->display_errors()` to my ajaxx success/error. So, if the data is not uploaded there's a message why it'is not uploaded. Too big or wrong extension. Sorry for long comment :D

Comment: To show error you need to send errors from server side using $this->upload->display_errors() and then in jquery if success flag is 0 you will get upl_error string in json response that you can use to show error. 
Check my updated answer.

Comment: It shows error `SyntaxError:JSON.parse:unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`. The error should say `The file is too big` because I upload file that exceed allowed size

Comment: Add  console.log(data) in your success callback and check what response you get from server. It should like this {"success"=0,"upl_error":"your error message"}  ( if error occurs )

Comment: I put it in AJAX error and it works.

`error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown, data)
   {
    toastr.options = {
     closeButton : false,
     progressBar : false,
     showMethod : 'slideDown',
     timeOut  : 3000
    };
    
    toastr.error(errorThrown, 'Error...'); 
    
    if(data.upl_error)
    { toastr.error(data.upl_error, 'Error...'); }`

Answer (score 0):

**The AJAX error alert only shows alert when AJAX is not working**. This is working fine because, the case your file is not uploading is not an ajax error, its a normal code flow.

To handle it, you have to return some status to manage it in `success` of ajax like:

```
success: function(response)
{
    if(response == 1)
    {
        // do some thing
    }
    else
    {
        // do some thing
    }
}
```

PHP:

```
if( check here file uploads or not )
{
    echo 1;
}
else
{
    echo 0;
}
```

Comment: So,is it imposibble?

Comment: No its possible, show error in success block depends on the response returned by php script

Comment: how do I return the file_upload error text to ajax success block?

Comment: I'd like to return the text of `$this->upload->display_errors()`. So the user know why the data is not uploaded

Answer (score 0):

In success function to check response content, or use `http_response_code(500)` in php script to trigger ajax error function.